# What kind of engine to use for configuration rules checking?

Tags: .net

Sorry for poor English.

I have a configuration application where an user can 'manually' select or eliminate some features of a system, other features must be automatically selected or eliminated by application using rules.

The rules are in the form:
*a* **IMPLIES** *b*  (If feature *a* is selected, the feature *b* must be selected).
*b* **CONFLICTS** *c* (If feature *b* is selected, the feature *c* must be eliminated).
*d* **AND** *e* **IMPLIES** *f*  (If feature *d* and feature *e* is selected, the feature *f* must be selected).
etc...

Some rules can cause conflict, for example:
1) *a* **IMPLIES** *b*
2) *a* **IMPLIES** *c*
3) *b* **CONFLICTS** *c*
If feature *a* is selected, the state (selected/eliminated) of feature *c* cannot be determined, and I must be able to display the involved rules to the user.

I am looking for advises about what kind of engine (solver, checker, etc) to use.  n 
Preferably open source software I can use with .NET languages.

Thanks

Tonite

Comment: this question might help you  http://bit.ly/aaEDeI

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for some [logic programming solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_programming). Maybe [F#](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Sharp) is an option for you, but if you just need it to check configuration rules, this is the overkill.

If you want to implement it yourself: For simple rules if-Statements will also do the job (no, it's not a shame to counter simple problems with simple approaches). If the checking rules are complicated, volatile or even dynamic take a look on the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) (for more in depth information see [Evans & Fowler's article in PDF](http://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf)). It is suitable for complicated checking routines, but does not incur the additional cost of using a third party engine or even another implementation language.